# Regex to eliminate SQL insert values with multiple lines

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm migrating some BDD to a new structure and I need to make some changes in the structure. To do it, I start with a backup with the insert commands and using sublimetext2 and [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace) I create some script to adapt the inserts.

The problem I have is when I need to delete one of the column's values and some of the data is text that can be in multiple lines and I have multiple inserts.

I'm using this regex:

```
(.*table.*VALUES \(.*,)(.*,)(([\s\S]*,){12})(.*;)
    Replace by: \1\3\5
```

And this is the data:

```
INSERT INTO table (cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, colf, colg, colg, colh, coli, colj, colk, coll, colm, coln, colo, colp, colq, colr, cols, colt, culu) VALUES (1, '2', 3, NULL, '5', 6, '7', '8', 9, NULL, NULL, 12, '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', 20, '21', 22');
INSERT INTO table (cola, colb, colc, cold, cole, colf, colg, colg, colh, coli, colj, colk, coll, colm, coln, colo, colp, colq, colr, cols, colt, culu) VALUES (1, '2', 3, NULL, '5', 6, '7', '8', 9, NULL, NULL, 12, '13', '14', ' 

                              15

                            ', '16', '17', '18', '19', 20, '21', '22');
```

If I use the regex with just one line it will eliminate the column number *9*, but when I code it in sublimetext2 or input both lines together or more it will not work because it doesn't separate both INSERT INTO statements.

[Here is the example not working](http://regex101.com/r/sG7mM1)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try with ungreedy quantifiers:

```
(.*?table.*?VALUES \((?:[\s\S]*?,){14})([\s\S]*?,)(([\s\S]*?,)*?)(.*?;)
```

(if you want to test it with regex101 don't forget to add the g modifier)

notice:

with RegReplace, you can set greedy to false and remove all the question marks.

RegReplace support the dotall modifier thus you can replace `[\s\S]` by `.` and add `(?s)` before

example with the 2 notices:

```
(?s)(.*table.*VALUES \((?:.*,){14})(.*,)((.*,)*)(.*;)
```

Comment: Thanks @Casimir, seems like it's almost there but with that regex it's not possible to delete the column values because it selects all.
[Here is the try out](http://regex101.com/r/rJ4fT7).
But it looks like the solution is going to be about the ungreedy quantifiers.

Comment: @AntonioNóRodríguez: I have tested it with regex101 (like you) and it works well with $1$3$5 replacement

Comment: Yes, but you always take out the '2'. I tried to take out the '9' by changing the number on the regex but it never takes a different one.

Comment: @AntonioNóRodríguez: in other words: it select all but with two occurences of the pattern, test it with the g option, to be sure.

Comment: I did it in the [try out](http://regex101.com/r/rJ4fT7) and it takes both _2_ of both inserts correctly. The problem is when I want to take any other value different than the _2_. If I want to take out the _9_ I would change the regex number from 12 to other, but it will still take out the _2_.

Comment: @AntonioNóRodríguez: ok, try my edit and choose the value you want to remove (number-1)

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. I'll try to understand it on the page. Thanks a lot :)